# How to print out the biggest numbers in a map

Tags: java

I was reading about maps in java. I want to go through a map of different numbers and print out the biggest 3 numbers in the map. Here is my code :

```
public class Test {

    private static int number=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        m.put("haha", 1);
        m.put("aa", 2);
        m.put("rewq", 3);
        m.put("la", 12);
        m.put("oia", 10);
        m.put("uyta", 4);
        m.put("jpa", 5);


        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {

            if (e.getValue() > number) {
                number = e.getValue();
            }

        }
        m.values().remove(number);
        System.out.println(number);

        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {

            if (e.getValue() > number) {
                number = e.getValue();
            }

        }
        m.values().remove(number);
        System.out.println(number);


        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {

            if (e.getValue() > number) {
                number = e.getValue();
            }

        }
        m.values().remove(number);
        System.out.println(number);

    }

}
```

The output is

```
12
12
12
```

How can I change the code to make it printing like this :

```
12
10
5
```

Thanks

Comment: Java 8 only:
`m.values().stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: You'd make life easier for yourself if you used a for loop to search/remove/print 3 times, instead of duplicating the code.

Comment: @DominikSandjaja But that takes O(n) memory and O(n log n) to sort. top n should take n (3 in this case) memory and linear time.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann surely you need O(n) memory to store the top n items?

Comment: The classic "algorithms" solution is to use an O(n) [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the 3rd largest number, then scan over the values again, keeping every element greater than or equal to the 3rd largest. It's a bit messier when you have duplicates, but it's the same general idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're iterating three times over the same numbers with the same condition without resetting the maximal found number. Your code basically finds the biggest number and then compares every item in the map for a *bigger* number two times. Of course that finds nothing and prints the previously found biggest number.

What you rather want is:

- get all values (not entry sets)
- sort the values
- print out the first three

In Java that's:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(m.values());
Collections.sort(values);
// turn ascending to descending
Collections.reverse(values);
System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d, %d", values.get(0), values.get(1), values.get(2)));
```

Sorting all values even though you only need the first three is some calculation overhead, but for lists of less than thousands of entries it's neglectible.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you have a single variable for a max value, so by the end of your program you will always have your largest being printed because you are still comparing it to the largest value. This is why you get the same value everytime. You can read all the numbers into an arraylist and then call the collections.sort method and take the top 3 from that and print those.

With what you have currently you could also do the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    //this makes sure you aren't comparing the same largest number everytime
    number = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() > number) {
            number = e.getValue();
        }
    }
    m.values().remove(number);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: *"Currently you have a single variable for a max value, so by the end of your program you will always have your largest being printed."* Looks like you missed that OP tries to delete the previously selected max number before finding the next one. So you should also explain if and why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use Java 8 features to achieve what you want

```
        Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        m.put("haha", 1);
        m.put("aa", 2);
        m.put("rewq", 3);
        m.put("la", 12);
        m.put("oia", 10);
        m.put("uyta", 4);
        m.put("jpa", 5);


        m.values()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .limit(3)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```